# I like to do [ A bit of housework / housework ] while XYX

Tags: exam-questions

> I like to do a bit of housework while the children are at school.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ?

My context of asking question is that just like in this sentence *We received a great deal of complaints.* Its better to use *number* instead of *great deal* as complaints are countable , Is it fine to use *a bit of* in the given sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatical, and it's a good way to give the reader an idea of how much housework gets done while the children are at school.

When we *don't* include this information, the sentence would look like this:

> I like to do housework while the children are at school.

This is ambiguous! It could mean one hour's worth of housework, or six hours of frenzied cleaning. This is why we can use modifiers with *housework*, such as:

> I did a lot of housework this week.
>   I only did a tiny bit of housework this week; I spent most of the time working on my car.

This works with other uncountable nouns, too,

The people who live on that island have a lot of freedom.
I only see a tiny bit of humor in that joke.

But you wouldn't quantify such nouns in ways like this:

> The people on that island only have three freedoms.
>   The I only see two humors in that joke.
>   I did twelve houseworks this week – my house is spotless!

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely correct. Oxford definition of *bit*:

> 1: A small piece, part, or **quantity** of something.
>  ‘give the duck a bit
>   of bread’
>  ‘he read bits of his work to me’